# attempt to load oracle client libraries threw badimageformatexception

Tags: c#-4.0, badimageformatexception

I am using Visual Studio 2012. I installed Oracle 64bit Client. My Operating system is Win7 64 bit. I want add a new Oracle DB connection but when I enter username password etc. and click 'Test Connection' button, I see this error:

```
attempt to load oracle client libraries threw badimageformatexception 

This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit 
Oracle client components installed.
```

But my Oracle Client is 64 bit. There is no any 32 bit component on my system.

I am also having problem on Oracle.DataAccess.dll added to my references. I tried EVERY COMBINATION which is Any CPU, x86i x64 platforms but nothing has changed. Everytime I get BadImageFormatException.

I searched for another questions but nothing has changed. I also tried IIS App Pool Enable 32bit applications property to True but it doesnt work.

Any suggestions? What else I can try?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498391/attempt-to-load-oracle-client-libraries-threw-badimageformatexception)